# SQL Server PIVOT query

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have been struggling with this query for some time now. I get the following error:

```
Error in WHERE clause near 'PIVOT'
Unable to parse query text.
```

My query currently looks like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
SELECT tblDatCash.colDate as dt , tblDatCash.colAccount as acc,  
       tblDatCash.colCash as cash
FROM tblDatCash
WHERE tblDatCash.colAccount = '5002680000CHF' or  tblDatCash.colAccount  ='5002680000EUR'
) DataTable
PIVOT
(
sum( [cash]) 
FOR [acc] IN ([5002680000CHF], [5002680000EUR])
) AS PIVOT
```

To make things clearer, here is an extract of what is in the table tblDatCash:

```
colAccount              colCash      colDate
02300000407319600000H   1512.83      2015-08-17 00:00:00.000
02300000362949610000Y   16537855.97  2015-08-17 00:00:00.000
5002680000CHF           3228530.89   2015-08-17 00:00:00.000
5002680000EUR           133825.33    2015-08-17 00:00:00.000
5002680000USD           694247.14    2015-08-17 00:00:00.000
```

Can anyone help me out on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `PIVOT` keyword as a table alias on the last line of the query which you can't do. Change it to:

```
) AS P
```

or something else that is not a keyword.